# How to set a HashSet<string> as a Value in Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashset

I have an array of strings called "subjects".
I'm trying to fill my dictionary and using some class as key and HashSet "string" as Value, but can't make it properly and receive an error "cannot convert string[] to System.Collections.Generic.HashSet"string"".
So what i need to put in my dictionary to make it work?

```
Dictionary<Student, HashSet<string>> studentSubjectDict = new Dictionary<Student, HashSet<string>>();

studentSubjectDict.Add(Student11, subjects);
```

Comment: `new HashSet<string>(subjects)` or `subjects.ToHashSet()` (with LINQ and recent versions of .NET).

Comment: Would it not be more sensible to have your Student have a property Subjects (that could be a hashset if you want)

Comment: Problem solved thanks to @Jeroen Mostert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jeron Mostert said, `new HashSet<string>(subjects)` or `subjects.ToHashSet()` solve this problem